# Error When Looping Through DataSet and Inserting into ListBox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datatable, dataset

This is a windows forms application. I have a class Program.cs and a form DeployerConsole.cs with a ListBox on it. I am attempting to loop through the results from the SQL query.  I am having trouble and getting a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' error when I try to access the data and insert it into my listbox on the form.

EDIT: The SQL Query is completing successfully and the Console.WriteLine is outputting to the output window properly with the correct data.

```
    static void LoadServers()
    {
        DeployerConsole DC = (DeployerConsole)Application.OpenForms["DeployerConsole"];
        //DeployerConsole DC = new DeployerConsole();
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=XXX; database=XXX; uid=XXX; pwd=XXX;Integrated Security=true;Connection Lifetime=5;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
        myConnection.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT ServerName FROM DeployServers", myConnection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommand);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            DC.listBox1.Items.Add(dr["ServerName"].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(dr["ServerName"].ToString());
        }
       
    }
```

EDIT: Added Screenshot

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Anyone have any suggestions or provide guidance as to what I am doing wrong?

EDIT (ANSWER):  Well, I moved the code from the class to the form. No problems accessing the listBox now.  However, I still would like to know the solution to this.

Comment: is listBox1 instantiated? What does the debugger say when you mouse over it in Visual Studio during a debugging session?

Comment: Exactly which line is this failing on?

Comment: DC.listBox1.Items.Add(dr["ServerName"].ToString());

Comment: btw what is 'DC'? Is that a form? and is it 'this' form or a reference to another form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worth a try (just for testing purposes) to try:

```
if(DC.listBox1 != null)
{
  DC.listBox1.Items.Add(dr["ServerName"].ToString());
}
```

That could give you a clue, if which you might need to make sure someplace listBox1 is instantiated.

```
 DC.listBox1 = new ListBox();
```

**EDIT**

It might be that DC is not being correctly passed by reference to the static method.
It might be better to change the signature of the Method to accept the form.

```
static void LoadServers(Form form)
{ 
 ...
 form.listBox1.Items.Add(...)
 ... etc.
}
```

and call it assuming from the form:

```
Helper.LoadServers(this);
```

Comment: When I use 'DC.listBox1 = new ListBox();' I also get the same error. I am thinking it has something to do with how the class is talking to the listbox on the form (DeployerConsole).

Comment: That is also a strong possibility. I noticed that is a static method. Does the method somehow have the correct reference to a singleton of the form? Is DC == null?

Comment: Even when using the check 'if (DC.listBox1 != null)' its throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by this line of code:

```
DeployerConsole DC = (DeployerConsole)Application.OpenForms["DeployerConsole"];
```

I suspect the OpenForms property is returning null because you have not explicitly set the name of your form (e.g. form.Name = "DeployerConsole";).

Comment: Can you expand on your explanation and example?

Comment: I'm just saying that Application.OpenForms["DeployerConsole"] may be returning null because you haven't set the name of your form.

Comment: The name is set in the properties window to DeployerConsole. I think you are right stating that it is returing null. I believe that I am doing something wrong when I am linking to the form from the class.

Comment: Please see my revised answer.